# Translate this camel route snippet from Java DSL to Blueprint xml

Tags: java, xml, apache, apache-camel

Does anyone know how to write this camel route snippet in blueprint xml's sytax?

```
.setHeader("headerName").method(beanInstance, "methodToGetHeaderValue")
```

I assume it's something like this but I can't get the exact syntax down.

```
<setHeader headerName="theHeader"> 
    <bean id="beanId" ref="MyBean" method="BeanMethod"/> 
</setHeader>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the tag you're looking for to invoke a method is `<method>`.

The Camel docs have an example of [setting a header](http://camel.apache.org/constant.html) and [invoking a method](http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html). Putting these together, you get:

```xml
<setHeader headerName="theHeader">
  <method ref="MyBean" method="methodToGetHeaderValue" />
</setHeader>
```

Comment: Thanks Ray, I actually found this documentation (http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html) not long after I posted this question and I arrived at the same conclusion as you. Thank you for your really prompt response though!